# Powershell how to set body of a newly created xml tag?

Tags: xml, powershell, tags

I'm creating new xml tags to a file as follows:

```
$MediaSizeWidth = $XmlDocument.CreateElement("psk:MediaSizeWidth"," ")
$MediaSizeWidth.SetAttribute("psf2:psftype","ScoredProperty")
$MediaSizeWidth.SetAttribute("xsi:type","xsd:integer")
$node.appendChild($MediaSizeWidth)
```

This creates a tag that looks like following:

```
<psk:MediaSizeWidth psftype="ScoredProperty" type="xsd:integer" />
```

I would also need to set the content to the tag, so the new tag looks like following:

```
<psk:MediaSizeWidth psftype="ScoredProperty" type="xsd:integer">the content here</psk:MediaSizeWidth>
```

So, how do I add the actual content to the crated tag?

I'm trying to generate a following structure:

```
<psk:PageMediaSize psf2:psftype="Feature">
   <psk:SOMESIZE psftype="Option" xmlns:psk=" ">
      <psk12:PortraitImageableSize psftype="Property" type="psf2:ImageableAreaType" xmlns:psk12=" " />
      <psk:MediaSizeHeight psftype="ScoredProperty" type="xsd:integer">some_number_here</psk:MediaSizeHeight>
      <psk:MediaSizeWidth psftype="ScoredProperty" type="xsd:integer">some_other_number_here</psk:MediaSizeWidth>
   </psk:SOMESIZE>
</psk:PageMediaSize>
```

Comment: You can set the InnerText property on the node - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.innertext?view=net-5.0

Comment: @mclayton I tried that but I'm getting error on one case that it does not exist...

Comment: Try `$xmlText = $XmlDocument.CreateTextNode("the content here"); $PortraitImageablSize.AppendChild($xmlText)`

Comment: @Theo `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression`

Comment: You did create `$PortraitImageableSize` first didn't you? Please show us some valid xml to work with

Comment: @Theo Actually this was the case, I typoed the variable. Now your suggestion works!

Comment: HA, I see I did the same typo (forgot an `e`).. Glad it works for you ;)